# Error in Android while creating a directory

Tags: java, android, external

I'm trying to créate a directory in Android. I have checked permissions and tested the app in two devices with Android 6 and Android 5 and works without problems. When I have checked it in a S3 with Cyanogenmod it fails to créate the directory. The code is very simple:

```
        File d = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + obra);
    if(!d.exists())
    {
        boolean result=d.mkdir();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + obra}, null, null);
    }
```

result is false in the S3.

As I said, I have checked permissions and the app asked me in Android 6 for the permissions, everything seems ok and Works in other devices. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you have an external storage at all? If there is no external storage avaialble in your device, the `!d.exists()` check would still return true

Comment: any exceptions in logcat ? or any `try` with empty `catch`?

Comment: I have a SD card. In fact, if I use EZExplorer or any similar program the path is perfect valid. And no, there's no exceptions

Comment: `the path is perfect valid`. Yes for reading. But can other apps -not-  write too? Try also File:canWrite() on directories there.

Comment: Well, it seems that it works. File:canWrite() was false, so I checked a bit more and it seems that when I'm debugging in that phone attached to the computer, computer blocks the file system. When I have tried the app unpluged it seems to Works. Thanks to everybody for your helping.